# How to precheck whether application is installed or not before the prerequiste installing it

Tags: vb.net, prerequisites

I have developed an application which is one click installation and I have developed the package for AccessDataBaseEngine using BMG Software.it will be installing AccessdatabaseEngine as Prerequisite,it will be installing the AccessdatabaseEngine before the installation of My application. Now the question is how can I check whether AccessdatabaseEngine is installed or not in the system before prompting the user to install AccessdatabaseEngine so that if its priorly installed in system than it doesnt request to install AccessdatabaseEngine, but directly install with the application rather than asking for reinstalling it.

Please help me with this.

Comment: If your using clickonce deployment it should skip already installed prerequisitsmautomaticly

Comment: but its not skiping the Prerequisites automatically as I have done the package of it using BMG software, what Tag I should include in package to check it automatically

Comment: you should include how you made the installer with the question as most people will assume its one of the basic microsoft installer makers.